# Launch windows 8 app using shortcut key

Tags: c#, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

Can I assign a keyboard shortcut key combination to launch my windows 8 app via code without intervention from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegisterHotKey` is not available for Windows Store Apps. [Discussion on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nn-NO/winappswithnativecode/thread/6d15817b-4410-46a7-b98a-a1971125ef41)

When looking into the issue, I assumed it could be because of one of these 2 things:

**Battery Life Concerns** Monitoring system wide events take more processing, but if the filtering of they hotkey was done at an OS level, I believe the cost wouldn't be too great compared to having all keyboard events monitored, so that leaves us with:

**Consistency Across Platforms** Seeing how the virtual keyboard doesn't include keys like *Windows* or *Alt*, I guess it would be impossible to perform most HotKeys on Surface devices. Instead of having "a better experience" on the PC, they probably decided simply remove the feature for consistency.

If anyone has a better explanation I would like to hear it!

Comment: The main reason is application separation and isolation.